# set focus to iframe body/content in firefox?

Tags: html, firefox, iframe, focus

i have an ifram, which has hidden visibility. 
i click on  button - iframe will be visible and i want to focus on its body/content.
because now i must click on button and then into iframe, so thats two clicks. i want to do it on one click, but dont know how to focus in firefox.

in explorer it is ok:

```
var iframe_window = window.frames["myFrame"];
iframe_window.document.body.focus();
```

try lot of examples for firefox, but they dont work. anybody know how to do it in firefox ? thanks.

Comment: Why using frame and iframe !!! (sick)

Comment: doing something like rte html editor.. dont find better idea than use iframe. dont know if it is possible to do without an iframe.

Answer (score 6):

Try to set the focus to `iframe_window` first and to your actual content next:

```
iframe_window.focus();
iframe_window.contentDocument.body.focus();
```

Answer (score 1):

Not every element supports `.focus()`. Can you focus the element, you are trying to focus programmatically, using keyboard/mouse?

Focus can go to elements form elements or 'a' tags or a span with contant-editable property set to true.

Find such an element in the iframe and try focusing on that. Should work !!

Comment: Focus can also go to elements with a `tabindex` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Does

```
iframe_window.contentDocument.body.focus();
```

work?

Comment: How about when using 

var iframe_window = document.getElementById('myFrame');

having myFrame as the id attribute on the iframe?

Comment: yes, i have 'myFrame' as the id attribute and also as name attribute, but it still doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

I think you might have to actually focus something *inside* the iFrame; the iFrame itself wouldn't do anything with the focus, but maybe you can put focus a DIV inside it, or even a widget?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the focus to the <iframe> element itself.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem (only in firefox), I seem to have solved it by setting the focus on the iframe only ***after*** you're certain that the iframe has completely loaded. In my iframe html:

```
<body onLoad="init();>
```

Javascript inside the iframe page:

```
this.init = function(){
    parent.focusframe();
}
```

And this javascript is in the parent window:

```
this.focusframe = function(){
    var fr = document.getElementById("gameframe");
    fr.contentWindow.focus();
}
```