# Focus in an iframe in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, iframe, focus, onload

I shall open a dialog which contains an iframe, then set the focus inside the iframe once the dialog is opened.

Currently, I try to get the focus on the iframe when the content is loaded:

```
<iframe src="../credits.html" onload="this.contentWindow.focus()"></iframe>
```

It works fine for all browsers except for Firefox, and I don't understand why.

Can someone tell me why?
Thanks

Comment: I would like to know this too. It's 2015 and Firefox does not seem to allow an iframe to even focus on itself or anything inside it. This extremely simple fiddle does not work in Firefox: http://jsfiddle.net/4b32fgd8/

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1508348/set-focus-to-iframe-body-content-in-firefox?rq=1

Comment: @user2867288 The reason your fiddle does not work is probably because JSFiddle is setting the focus into their code editors, or otherwise stealing the focus so that your frame cannot. I can't reproduce this issue ourside JSFiddle, even this code works: `<iframe src="https://fiddle.jshell.net/4b32fgd8/show/"></iframe>`

Comment: As for the original question, this code works about half the time for me, and fails the other half. Very strange.

Comment: maybe it's a timing problem

Comment: It might be added before loading the dom. Place the script @  the bottom or inside document.ready

Answer (score 4):

Firefox seems not to have contentWindow property, you should use contentDocument

**Update**:

After a small debate I came up with a better solution:

```
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $("#xframe").bind("load", function(){
        $(this).contents().find("#xa").focus();
    });
});

  </script>
</head>
<body>
<iframe id="xframe" src="./y.html"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

In this example, I assume that there's a input field inside y.html that has a "xa" id. It worked both on Chrome and Firefox.

**Old answer**

Even better you should use jquery, something like:

```
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#xframe").focus();
   });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
<iframe id="xframe" src="./y.html"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

Of course you could do some extra check to see if the iframe is ready.

More info can be found here http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_frame_contentwindow.asp

Comment: I guess the question I have is more along the lines of how does a frame focus itself in firefox. e.g. how do you make this jsfiddle work in firefox? http://jsfiddle.net/4b32fgd8/

Comment: It's not working on jsfiddle because something else is stealing the focus. If you run it on fullscreen, it will work: http://jsfiddle.net/4b32fgd8/show/

Comment: The setInterval only starts to work when I physically click on the preview pane, and stops working when I click out. This means Firefox is imposing a restriction that other browsers don't.

Comment: If you take a look at http://rfsbsb.github.io/ you'll see your code working. The fact is that jsfiddle editor is stealing the focus. If you go to https://github.com/rfsbsb/rfsbsb.github.io you'll see the source and note that I used a jQuery document.ready. If you don't do this way (or with an alternative way, like setInterval) your code is executed before the DOM is ready thus it won't work.

Comment: You're wrong about the domready thing. Try this http://jsfiddle.net/2f67kqmt/ in Chrome. Then try it in Firefox. It works in Chrome. It doesn't work in Firefox. That's the problem. It looks to me like Firefox sandboxes iframe focus events until the user focuses on the iframe.

Answer (score 1):

Try do this using jquery

```
  // focus an input in iframe
 $('#xframe').contents().find('input').get(0).focus()


 // or simply iframe window
var iframe= $('#xframe')[0];
var iframewindow= iframe.contentWindow?     iframe.contentWindow :     iframe.contentDocument.defaultView;
iframewindow.focus()
```